# Trying to capture option+i in firefox on OS X using JQuery

Tags: jquery, firefox, keypress, keydown, keyup

I am having a hard time trying to get jquery's keypress to catch the option/alt + i using Firefox in OS X. Firefox also doesn't like option u or a. I understand these are reserved for special characters but it works with chrome, so I'm a bit lost. Here is the code.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
if(e.altKey && String.fromCharCode( e.which ).toLowerCase() == 'i')
    console.log('yes');});

$(document).keyup(function(e){
if(e.altKey && String.fromCharCode( e.which ).toLowerCase() == 'i')
    console.log('yes');});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
if(e.altKey && String.fromCharCode( e.which ).toLowerCase() == 'i')
    console.log('yes');});
```

Comment: You can trigger all the events using $(document).on('keyup keypress...

Comment: To type accent characters, like ñ Á á the option key is used. So when a user presses option key and i only ˆis show and wait for the actual letter to apply the accent . Somehow firefox doesn't bubble the even well for us to catch it .